Set inactive button on MUI v5 paginate and paginateItem
I want to deactivate a paginate button in MUI paginate component
              <PaginationItem
                  component="button"
                  slots={{
                    first: () => <>First</>,
                    previous: ArrowBackIcon,
                    next: ArrowForwardIcon,
                    last: () =>  <>Last</>,
                  }}
                  {...item}
                />

The button I want to show disable is the last button when a total count is under a certain number.
I can't seem to be able to use the disabled prop and also I want to show the button as disbled. I think the disabled prop removes the button.
I am using MUI V5 right now but can't seem to get this to work. Open to upgrading to V6.
